# Retrieving files from AWS S3 in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I uploaded multiple PDF files in following path (`user/pdf/`) in AWS S3. So that path for each file is going to be like `user/pdf/file1.pdf`, `user/pdf/file2.pdf`, etc.

In my website(Angular front-end and Rails backend), I'm trying to do 3 things.
1) Retrieving files in certain path (`user/pdf/`).
2) Make a view which lists names of the files I retrieved from certain path.
3) Let users to click the name of the file and it will open the file using S3 endpoint
4) Delete the file by clicking a button.

I was looking into AWS S3 doc, but I could not find related API calls from the doc. Would love to get some help on performing above actions.

Comment: Did you read this API doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should review the [ruby S3 sdk doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3.html)

1. listing objects from a bucket

   ```
   # enumerate ALL objects in the bucket (even if the bucket contains
   # more than 1k objects)
   bucket.objects.each do |obj|
     puts obj.key
   end

   # enumerate at most 20 objects with the given prefix
   bucket.objects.with_prefix('photos/').each(:limit => 20) do |photo|
     puts photo.key
   end
   ```
2. getting an object

   ```
   # makes no request, returns an AWS::S3::S3Object
   obj = bucket.objects['key']
   ```
3. deleting an object

   ```
   bucket.objects.delete('abc')
   ```

Comment: Hello. What is 'key' and 'abc' in #2 and #3?

Comment: Its the same it the S3 key in your case file1.pdf including full path

Comment: so key is basically just a path including file name, right? Separately, I can assign certain path in `with_prefix('photos/')` right?

Comment: Exact in your case Will be user/pdf/

Comment: I passed the path in `bucket.objects.with_prefix('photos/').each(:limit => 20) do |photo|
  puts photo.key
end` and it's not working. do you know why?